# problemas en Test con Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, dusk

Estoy comenzando con laravel dusk y siguiendo un tutorial es que cree este primer test

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
        $browser->loginAs($user)
        ->visit('/')
        ->type('body', 'Mi primer status')
        ->press('#create-status')
        ->assertSee('Mi primer status');
    });
```

Esta es mi vista Home

```
<form action="{{route('statuses.store')}}" method="POST">
@csrf
<textarea name="body" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button id="create-status">Publicar estado</button>
```

el test me arroja el siguiente resultado

> Tests\Browser\UserCanCreateStatusesTest::users_can_create_statuses
>   Did not see expected text [Mi primer status] within element [body].
>   Failed asserting that false is true.

No entiendo por que el test falla si en teoria los campos existen, con los nombres correctos.

Comment: Estás en SO en español, por favor traduce tu pregunta o puede terminar cerrada

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, pudiste resolverlo?